# undefined reference to 'XXX' after using #define _GNU_SOURCE

Tags: c, postgresql, posix, gnu, undefined-reference

I used `search.h` for my c program, where I need to put `#define _GNU_SOURCE` to the first line in order to introduce multiple hash tables. But after that, errors like `undefined reference to 'log10'` and `undefined reference to 'PQntuples'` popped up. I certainly need all the packages there, how should I now compile the program? Any help would be deeply appreciated! Thanks.

The headers:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
// library for psql
#include <libpq-fe.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <search.h>
```

```
int main(void){
    char host[] = "localhost";
    char port[] = "5432";
    char db_name[] = "db_name";
    char user[] = "test_usr";
    char password[] = "123456";
    sprintf(db_str, "host=%s port=%s dbname=%s user=%s password=%s",
             host, port, db_name, user, password);
    PGconn *db_connection = DBConnect(db_str);

    struct hsearch_data htab;
    hcreate_r(10, &htb);
    ENTRY e, *ep;
    e.key = "test";
    e.data = (void *) 1;
    hsearch_r(e, ENTER, &ep, &htab);
}
```

And this was how I compile the file:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -I/home/userX/postgresql/include -L/home/userX/postgresql/lib -lm -lpq -g my_program.c
```

Comment: Please provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is `db_str` and `htb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifiy the libraries at the end of the command line

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -I/home/userX/postgresql/include \
      -L/home/userX/postgresql/lib -g my_program.c -lpq -lm
//                                                 ^^^^^^^^
```

gcc looks at required symbols left to right on the command line.
With the libraries before the source files, when gcc processes the `-llib` argument it does not have any requirements and therefore does not "extract" any function from the library.

Comment: Alt: `... $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libpq) -lm`

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked!!! Should I always do that? and I really would like to know why there is such a difference between these two?

Comment: Yes, basically always specify libraries at the end.  I added an explanation to my post :)

Comment: @heisthere And you should generally put the most "low level" libraries last. `m` (the math lib) is pretty low level and `pq` may use stuff in it so `pq` should be put before `m`.

Comment: Thanks @TedLyngmo... that's also because of the way gcc deals with libraries. If you say `-lm -lpq` and pq needs something from the math library it will not be "extracted".

Comment: Disclaimer I have no idea how other compilers/linkers deal with it. I just always say `-lwhatever` last and it works :-)

Comment: It's all in the linker's documentation. Each listed library is searched only for open references in the order given. There are no "outer" loops. (Being able to read is an advantage. ;-)

Comment: @thebusybee ... unless the "outer loop" linker options `-Wl,--start-group` _libraries with circular dependencies_ `-Wl,--end-group` are used. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Correct.